# Kafka based distributed scheduler

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, quartz-scheduler, apache-kafka-streams, distributed

We have a use case wherein we are getting millions of events each day in Kafka. Each event would be like:

{"id": 123, "state": "start/in-transit/stop", "ts":"01-02-2021 12:00:00"}

So for each id we can have multiple events.

We need to generate alerts in case any one state has not been received for a particular id in a stream of these events after say xx days. Example for id 123 if we didn't receive in transit event after 5 days.

One way is to store everything in a data lake and run spark jobs continuously on top of it.

My question is: can we schedule jobs after xx days for each of these IDs and empower it using Kafka so that it becomes distributed.

Doing this we would not be continuously polling and checking if an alert condition is breached rather a job would be scheduled at a particular time for which we can query for the alert condition.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a compacted topic of in-progress events that store all start/in-transit states with a stop being a delete to remove the ID from a KTable.

However, you'll still need to scan the table every second to verify that any timestamp doesn't exceed its window